# How to find resolution of TTY I'm using?

Tags: resolution, tty

I can get to a TTY in Ubuntu by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. Once I'm at a shell in this TTY, how can I find out what is the resolution of this TTY?

Note that the `GRUB_GFXMODE` in my `/etc/default/grub` file is commented out. So, I cannot find out the resolution from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your current terminal:

```
stty size
```

If you want to know the resolution of another terminal use this:

```
stty -F /dev/tty1 size
```

Or for an `ssh` session:

```
stty -F /dev/pts/1 size
```

Another option is to use a tool called `resize`:

```
resize
```

Sample output:

```
COLUMNS=146;
LINES=43;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```

Comment: How can I map that to pixels?